# Docker: browsing to container on host computer not working

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, debian, virtual-machine

I am running a basic web application (PHP) inside Docker on a Debian VM, using Docker Compose.
When preforming sudo docker-compose up -d all containers start running just fine.

I have my ports setup as follows: 8007 for the application itself, 8008 for PHPMyAdmin, 9009 for Portainer.

The IP of the Debian VM is 192.168.56.102

When browsing using curl inside the VM to http://192.168.56.102:8007 the page loads without issues.

However, when browsing to the same URL on my Windows 10 host (Chrome) I get a connection timeout.

Pinging to 192.168.56.102 from host to VM and viceversa works fine, and so does SSH.

Does anyone know why I can't browse to these pages, eventhough everything works fine within the VM and the host and VM are clearly able to communicate?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any firewall rules in your vm that would prevent connections on port 8007?

Comment: In my desperate attempts to get this working, I have completly flushed the Debian firewall (which is basically like turning it off) but to no avail. Host firewall is also off. Also sorry in case this wasn't clear: none of the ports are accessible from the host, not just 8007.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem.

As suggested by @larsks some firewall rule inside Debian was blocking the connection. I had already tried `/sbin/iptables -F` which flushes the firewall rules, which I thought was enough, but it turns out that's not the case.

After running all these commands, the Debian firewall was completly reset and the issue was fixed:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```